# How to add the phonegap 3.5.0 plugin storage?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

when I look at this documentation here [Phonegap Storage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) I can't find any hint how to add this plugin. There is a reference if I understand it right that the Storage plugin belongs to the WebView. But there is also no hint.

In the CLI from Phonegap [Add Features](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_add_features) there is a list of all plugins but there is no plugin Storage.

How can I add this plugin over CLI? Or must I implement it manually?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for adding the storage plugin. It is included in the PhoneGap core. You can directly start to use the API.

Comment: oh no, really? Nice that is why I can't find a hint how to implement it as a plugin. :-(
Thank you.